# two almost the same If and else statements where one produces correct output and the other stays empty

Tags: r, rstudio

So i have written a function to analyse a dataset, in this function i made an option to choose which organism should be used for converting IDs.  This is the function:

```
library( edgeR );
library( ggplot2 );
library( reshape );
library( FactoMineR );
library( biomaRt )

analyse <- function( counts, design, contrast, name, style, convert=F, organism = NULL ) {
  counts <- counts[ rowSums( counts, na.rm = TRUE ) > 0, ];
  y <- DGEList( counts = counts, genes = rownames( counts ) );
  y <- calcNormFactors( y );
  y <- estimateGLMCommonDisp( y, design );
  y <- estimateGLMTrendedDisp( y, design, df = 5 );
  y <- estimateGLMTagwiseDisp( y, design );

  fit <- glmFit( y, design );
  lrt <- glmLRT( fit, contrast = contrast );
  de <- decideTestsDGE( lrt, p = 0.05, adjust = "BH" );
  cpmY <- cpm( y );

  daf <- designAsFactor( design );
  orderedDesign <- design[ order( daf, names( daf ) ), ];
  tab <- data.frame(
    row.names = rownames( cpmY ),
    genes = rownames( cpmY ),
    de = de,
    cpmY[ ,order( daf, names( daf ) ) ]
  );

  aRepTab <- topTags( lrt, n = nrow( counts ) )$table;
  aRepTab$rank <- 1:nrow( counts );
#  repTab <- tab[ match( aRepTab$genes, rownames( tab ) ), ];

  repTab <- merge( aRepTab, tab, by = "genes", sort = FALSE );
  repTab <- repTab[ order( repTab$rank ), ];
#  data.frame(
#    row.names = rownames( aRepTab ),
#    aRepTab,
#    tab[ match( aRepTab$genes, tab$genes ), ]
#  )

  if(is.null(organism)==TRUE){
    organism <- 'human'
 }


  if(organism=='human'){
    if(convert == T){
      mart <- useDataset( "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl") )

      EnsembleIds <- repTab$genes
      convert<-getBM(
        filters= "ensembl_gene_id", 
        attributes= c( "ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_id", "entrezgene", "description" ),
        values= EnsembleIds,
        mart= mart )

      idx <- match(repTab$genes, convert$ensembl_gene_id)
      newdf <- merge( repTab,convert[ idx ,], by.x="genes", by.y="ensembl_gene_id" )
      convertGeneTable <- newdf[ sort( colnames ( newdf ) ) ]
      convertGeneTable <- convertGeneTable[ order( convertGeneTable$rank ), ];
      list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign,
        convertGeneTable = convertGeneTable
      );
    }
    else{
      list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign
      );
    }
  }
  if(organism=='mouse'){
    if(convert == T){
      mart <- useDataset( "mmusculus_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl") )

      EnsembleIds <- repTab$genes
      convert<-getBM(
        filters= "refseq_mrna", 
        attributes= c( "ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_id", "entrezgene", "description", "wikigene_name", "refseq_mrna" ),
        values= EnsembleIds,
        mart= mart )

      newdf <- merge( repTab,convert,by.x="genes", by.y="refseq_mrna" )
      convertGeneTable <- newdf[ sort( colnames ( newdf ) ) ]
      convertGeneTable <- convertGeneTable[ order( convertGeneTable$rank ), ];
      list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign,
        convertGeneTable = convertGeneTable
      );
    }
    else{
      list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign
      );
    }

  }
}
```

If i choose human it produces an empty list but if i choose mouse i get the correct result list. And even more strange if i run all code from the human if else statement it works as well. I have the feeling i miss a { or something like that but i have checked all of them and compared to the if else from mouse. Could not find anything strange. The data needed for this function is rather big and it are multiple files. I will try to provide all of them below:

```
counts <- structure(list(s2E = c(2038L, 0L, 73L, 121L, 75L, 69L, 46L, 1722L, 
219L, 222L), s6E = c(952L, 0L, 136L, 173L, 23L, 0L, 0L, 760L, 
2934L, 115L), s15E = c(940L, 0L, 98L, 138L, 219L, 0L, 260L, 1040L, 
233L, 182L), s16E = c(303L, 0L, 36L, 22L, 48L, 0L, 127L, 276L, 
7L, 4L), s18E = c(1168L, 0L, 34L, 69L, 65L, 0L, 656L, 601L, 57L, 
162L), s20E = c(365L, 0L, 28L, 16L, 633L, 0L, 1157L, 624L, 7L, 
348L), s21E = c(3195L, 0L, 318L, 200L, 1046L, 47L, 1719L, 1708L, 
328L, 928L), s22E = c(2990L, 0L, 62L, 191L, 16L, 33L, 199L, 1759L, 
237L, 397L), s23E = c(2160L, 0L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 1267L, 361L, 
86L, 3L), s25E = c(521L, 0L, 53L, 16L, 75L, 0L, 365L, 665L, 255L, 
127L), s26E = c(1141L, 0L, 236L, 56L, 266L, 16L, 215L, 450L, 
265L, 183L), s27E = c(808L, 0L, 181L, 99L, 158L, 0L, 1012L, 878L, 
494L, 92L), s28E = c(0L, 0L, 160L, 66L, 535L, 0L, 700L, 1774L, 
2509L, 70L), s29E = c(614L, 0L, 72L, 36L, 10L, 0L, 492L, 783L, 
23L, 38L), s30E = c(640L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 455L, 88L, 
123L), s32E = c(973L, 0L, 91L, 9L, 107L, 4L, 159L, 815L, 59L, 
132L), s33E = c(3966L, 0L, 336L, 126L, 433L, 0L, 7857L, 2962L, 
507L, 236L), s34E = c(5113L, 0L, 179L, 145L, 197L, 12L, 679L, 
1482L, 7150L, 1476L), s35E = c(4861L, 0L, 604L, 269L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 5181L, 31L, 1166L), s36E = c(3975L, 0L, 87L, 192L, 240L, 
0L, 1635L, 677L, 228L, 188L), s38E = c(1335L, 0L, 115L, 117L, 
231L, 0L, 1626L, 373L, 192L, 445L), s39E = c(1589L, 0L, 529L, 
297L, 370L, 0L, 115L, 1959L, 834L, 742L), s40E = c(1916L, 0L, 
51L, 79L, 140L, 0L, 79L, 1617L, 187L, 235L), s42E = c(2513L, 
0L, 82L, 53L, 0L, 0L, 1699L, 870L, 716L, 1023L)), .Names = c("s2E", 
"s6E", "s15E", "s16E", "s18E", "s20E", "s21E", "s22E", "s23E", 
"s25E", "s26E", "s27E", "s28E", "s29E", "s30E", "s32E", "s33E", 
"s34E", "s35E", "s36E", "s38E", "s39E", "s40E", "s42E"), row.names = c("ENSG00000000003", 
"ENSG00000000005", "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", 
"ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036", "ENSG00000001084", 
"ENSG00000001167"), class = "data.frame")

design <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(24L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("s2E", "s6E", "s15E", "s16E", "s18E", "s20E", "s21E", "s22E", 
    "s23E", "s25E", "s26E", "s27E", "s28E", "s29E", "s30E", "s32E", 
    "s33E", "s34E", "s35E", "s36E", "s38E", "s39E", "s40E", "s42E"
    ), c("(Intercept)", "lympNodes1")), assign = 0:1, contrasts = structure(list(
    lympNodes = "contr.treatment"), .Names = "lympNodes"))

contrast <- structure(c(0, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Levels = c("Intercept", "lympNodes1"), Contrasts = "lympNodes1"), .Names = c("Levels", 
"Contrasts")))

name <- 'subset.of.count'
style <- structure(list(color = structure(list(colIds = structure(list(
    subject = structure(c(4L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
    21L, 22L, 23L), .Label = c("15", "16", "18", "2", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35", "36", "38", "39", "40", "42", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = "subject", row.names = c("s2E", 
"s6E", "s15E", "s16E", "s18E", "s20E", "s21E", "s22E", "s23E", 
"s25E", "s26E", "s27E", "s28E", "s29E", "s30E", "s32E", "s33E", 
"s34E", "s35E", "s36E", "s38E", "s39E", "s40E", "s42E"), class = "data.frame"), 
    name = "subject", map = structure(c("#FF0000FF", "#FF4000FF", 
    "#FF8000FF", "#FFBF00FF", "#FFFF00FF", "#BFFF00FF", "#80FF00FF", 
    "#40FF00FF", "#00FF00FF", "#00FF40FF", "#00FF80FF", "#00FFBFFF", 
    "#00FFFFFF", "#00BFFFFF", "#0080FFFF", "#0040FFFF", "#0000FFFF", 
    "#4000FFFF", "#8000FFFF", "#BF00FFFF", "#FF00FFFF", "#FF00BFFF", 
    "#FF0080FF", "#FF0040FF"), .Names = c("15", "16", "18", "2", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
    "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "38", "39", "40", "42", "6"
    ))), .Names = c("colIds", "name", "map")), linetype = structure(list(
    colIds = structure(list(lympNodes = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = "lympNodes", row.names = c("s2E", 
    "s6E", "s15E", "s16E", "s18E", "s20E", "s21E", "s22E", "s23E", 
    "s25E", "s26E", "s27E", "s28E", "s29E", "s30E", "s32E", "s33E", 
    "s34E", "s35E", "s36E", "s38E", "s39E", "s40E", "s42E"), class = "data.frame"), 
    name = "lympNodes", map = structure(1:2, .Names = c("0", 
    "1"))), .Names = c("colIds", "name", "map"))), .Names = c("color", 
"linetype"))

convert <- TRUE
organism <- 'human'
```

Ill hope this is a reproducible subset of the data. I hope there is someone here that can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please narrow down your question. This is a lot of code to go through.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I told in the beginning that a subset of this data makes the function unrunnable i dont know how to narrow it down more. But i found my answer and btw the entire last code block is just my data? so its only one function. Anyway thanks for at least having a look to my problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the just assigning the list output and providing a return statement fixed the problem.  Although I couldn't explain the specific internals in R as to why it will only output the first one without the return statement is beyond my expertise.

```
analyse <- function( counts, design, contrast, name, style, convert=F, organism = NULL ) {
  counts <- counts[ rowSums( counts, na.rm = TRUE ) > 0, ];
  y <- DGEList( counts = counts, genes = rownames( counts ) );
  y <- calcNormFactors( y );
  y <- estimateGLMCommonDisp( y, design );
  y <- estimateGLMTrendedDisp( y, design );
  y <- estimateGLMTagwiseDisp( y, design );

  fit <- glmFit( y, design );
  lrt <- glmLRT( fit, contrast = contrast );
  de <- decideTestsDGE( lrt, p = 0.05, adjust = "BH" );
  cpmY <- cpm( y );

  daf <- designAsFactor( design );
  orderedDesign <- design[ order( daf, names( daf ) ), ];
  tab <- data.frame(
    row.names = rownames( cpmY ),
    genes = rownames( cpmY ),
    de = de,
    cpmY[ ,order( daf, names( daf ) ) ]
  );

  aRepTab <- topTags( lrt, n = nrow( counts ) )$table;
  aRepTab$rank <- 1:nrow( counts );
  #  repTab <- tab[ match( aRepTab$genes, rownames( tab ) ), ];

  repTab <- merge( aRepTab, tab, by = "genes", sort = FALSE );
  repTab <- repTab[ order( repTab$rank ), ];

  if(is.null(organism)==TRUE){
    organism <- 'human'
  }


  if(organism=='human'){
    if(convert == T){
      mart <- useDataset( "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl") )

      EnsembleIds <- repTab$genes
      convert<-getBM(
        filters= "ensembl_gene_id", 
        attributes= c( "ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_id", "entrezgene", "description" ),
        values= EnsembleIds,
        mart= mart )

      idx <- match(repTab$genes, convert$ensembl_gene_id)
      newdf <- merge( repTab,convert[ idx ,], by.x="genes", by.y="ensembl_gene_id" )

      convertGeneTable <- newdf[ sort( colnames ( newdf ) ) ]
      convertGeneTable <- convertGeneTable[ order( convertGeneTable$rank ), ];
      out <- list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign,
        convertGeneTable = convertGeneTable
      );
    }
    else{
      out <- list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign
      );
    }
  }
  if(organism=='mouse'){
    if(convert == T){
      mart <- useDataset( "mmusculus_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl") )

      EnsembleIds <- repTab$genes
      convert<-getBM(
        filters= "refseq_mrna", 
        attributes= c( "ensembl_gene_id", "external_gene_id", "entrezgene", "description", "wikigene_name", "refseq_mrna" ),
        values= EnsembleIds,
        mart= mart )

      newdf <- merge( repTab,convert,by.x="genes", by.y="refseq_mrna" )
      convertGeneTable <- newdf[ sort( colnames ( newdf ) ) ]
      convertGeneTable <- convertGeneTable[ order( convertGeneTable$rank ), ];
      out <- list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign,
        convertGeneTable = convertGeneTable
      );
    }
    else{
      out <- list(
        name = name,
        y = y,
        fit = fit,
        lrt = lrt,
        de = de,
        tab = tab,
        style = style,
        repTab = repTab,
        orderedDesign = orderedDesign
      );
    }

  }

  return(out)
}
```